# Casting base class to derived class

Tags: c#

Basically there're 2 classes.

```
class Motor {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}

class Title : Motor {
    int d;
    int e;
}
```

Now a function is passed with an instance of Motor class.

```
bool AssignNums(Motor m)
{
   Title t = (Title)m;   //throws exception
   //Do other things with "t"
}
```

And it's called from,

```
void AddNums()
{
   Motor m = new Motor();
   m.a = 23;
   m.b = 78;
   m.c = 109;
   AssignNums(m);
}
```

The above line where the casting is done, doesn't work. It throws a null pointer exception.

I tried:

```
bool AssignNums(Motor m)
{
   Title t = new Title();
    t  = (Title)m; // Doesn't work.
   //Do other things with "t"
}
```

The above approach also doesn't work.

Coming from a C++ background, it's kinda difficult to understand how casting works in C#.

In C++ below code will work.

```
bool AssignNums(Motor* m)
{
   Title* t = (Title*)m; //Will work
   //Do other things with "t"
}
```

How can this be done in C#? Without tons of code to implement "reflection" or something like that...

Comment: Please edit your question and show an example of code using `AssignNums`

Comment: There are two cast syntaxes in C#.  Try the other one: `if (m is Title t) { /* code */ }`.  In your code, you know `m` is a `Title` and you have a non-null variable that references it as a `Title`

Comment: It sounds like you are passing `null` into `AssignNums` when calling it. As @LeeTaylor suggested, can you edit your question to show how you're calling `AssignNums`?

Comment: Where are you calling `AssignNums`? It looks like you're passing an instance of the `Motor` base class.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I have updated the question with how AssignNums is being called.

Comment: The reason you get an exception is that you are passing a `Motor` to `AssignNums` and then casting it to the sub-class `Title`.  The object is not a `Title`, so the cast fails and throws.  By the way, in `C++`, you shouldn't be using old-fashioned C-style casts, you should be using `dynamic_cast<>`, `reinterpret_cast<>`, etc.

Comment: Your C++ code has undefined behaviour; you are not allowed to cast a pointer to an instance of a base class to a pointer to a derived class unless it really *is* an instance of the derived class! The whole point of C# is that it turns your bad C++ code into sensible behaviour: *crash the program* is sensible behaviour when the rules are broken.

Answer (score 6):

In C#, you can't cast an object to a more specific subclass. Imagine what could happen if it were possible:

```
class Foo : Motor
{
    int z;
}

Foo m = new Foo();

bool AssignNums(Motor m)
{
   Title t = (Title)m;   // Pretend it doens't throw an exception
   //Do other things with "t"
   t.d = 42; // Oopps! The actual object is Foo, not Title, so there is no field called d
             // InvalidCastException is thrown at the line that attempts the cast
}
```

You can convert it at runtime if the actual type is compatible with the desired one:

```
bool AssignNums(Motor m)
{
   Title t = m as Title;   
   if (t != null)
   {
       // Do stuff with t
   }
}
```

Beginning with C# 7, you can use the shorter form

```
bool AssignNums(Motor m)
{
   if (m is Title t)
   {
       // Do stuf with t
   }
}
```

If handling multiple subclasses, you can also use switch..when

```
switch (m)
{
    case Title t when m is Title:
        // Do something with t
        break;
    case Foo f when m is Foo:
        // Do something with f
        break;
}
```

Note, though, if you're branching based on the subclass present at runtime, it's a sign that you may have a design issue.

Comment: I think you need to make your description of casting clearer, you can cast to a subtype if the object is that subtype.  If you cast it to a type it isn't then you get an exception.

Comment: also, for completeness, would be worth showing the new 'switch when' syntax if you want to handle multiple subtypes

Comment: @KeithNicholas Great thought, added it.

Comment: Also, added a comment that the cast in the first example throws InvalidCastException. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Use the other C# casting syntax, and use a recent C# feature (that allows associating a variable to the cast immediately):

```
bool AssignNums(Motor m)
{
   if (m is Title t) {
      //Do things with "t"
   }
}
```

If you do it this way, you ignore incoming `m` instances that are not of type `Title`.  The `is` cast also never throws (neither does the related `as` operation).